# ROS 2 Alpha 2 ros1_bridge using DDS between two computers

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried the ROS 2 Alpha 2 ros1_bridge (i.e. dynamic_bridge)? Have you tried it between two computers?

In my case, I'd like to use the dynamic bridge on an Ubuntu machine with ROS1 nodes. I'd like to run some ROS 2.0 nodes on a Windows machine. So far I've tried the tutorial (https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/README.md) for the dynamic_bridge succcesfully on the same machine. When I try two machines I make sure that the network interface that's selected is the one on the same subnet as the other machine. I've read in DDS forums that as long as the machines are on the same subnet with multicast enabled, the topics should pass between the machines.

Machine 1 (Ubuntu with ROS2Alpha2 binaries)

- start roscore
- start dynamic_bridge
- rosrun roscpp_tutorials listener
- start echo of the /chatter topic

Machine 2 (Ubuntu with ROS2Alpha2 binaries)

- start ROS 2 talker

This setup works on one machine but not between machines on the same subnet with multicast enabled. Is this a limitation of the ROS 2 bridge code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222579/ros-2-alpha-2-ros1_bridge-using-dds-between-two-computers/) by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out. The computer with the ROS 2 talker had two interfaces on the same subnet. After I removed one of the network devices leaving only one interface on the same subnet as the receiving PC, the talker's messages were see by the dynamic_bridge and republished to ROS 1.

---

Originally posted by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) with karma: 275 on 2015-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0